# Automatically change calendar dates from php

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, icalendar, auto-update

I use php programming language and I have a .ics file.
I am interested in how to automatically change the date from my old calendar with new dates.
For example, I using the 2014 calendar with the October events, I want to automatically change the dates from my .ics file using php to May 2018.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: you'd need to be able to parse the ICS data and extract what you want, and write the data to wherever it needs to go. Tried anything yet? Is it the actual ICS file you want to alter, or the source of where that ICS came from? It's not clear? And why have you tagged google calendar? It's not mentioned at all in the question.